# c++: segmantation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, fault

The purpose of my program is reading words in a file and counting occurrences of each word.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v, vdist;
    string parola;
    int j=0;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        cout << "file opened\n";
        while (! myfile.eof() ) {
            myfile >> parola;
            v.push_back(parola);
        }
        cout << "dimensione file: " << v.size() << endl;
        for (int i=0; i< v.size(); i++) {
            cout << i << "   " << v[i] << endl;
        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        for (int i=0; i<= v.size()-1; i++) {
            if (v[i] != v[i+1]) {
                vdist[j] = v[i];
                cout << vdist[j] << endl;
                j++;
            }
            vdist[j]= v[v.size()-1];
            j++;
        }
    } else 
        cout << "file not opened\n";

    return 0;
}
```

All I want to do is create a vector `vdist` which contains all distinct words, and counting for each one the occurrence.  Obviously it's not the best method but it is just to learn.
The row who generates segmentation fault is this:

```
vdist[j] = v[i];
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vdist` is empty, so `vdist[j]` is out of bounds.

Instead, it looks like you want to push the value onto the end of the vector:

```
vdist.push_back(v[i]);
```

Once you make that change, the `j` variable will be redundant, so you should remove it.

You also have a problem on the final iteration, where `v[i+1]` is out of bounds. You'll need to fix that - perhaps by stopping one iteration earlier, or perhaps by treating the final iteration differently to the others.

Comment: Plus, as a general rule, when you access a container, make sure that the container exist if it's a pointer, and the index is not out of bound. If the container is from the stl you can use iterator to iterate through it, it's safer.

Comment: yesss!! i'm so stupid!! thank you very much, now it perfectly works! Thanks again!